# nested IF statement 'object defined' error?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want column AX to do a VLOOKUP if column F doesn't have any value in the cell. If it does, I want it to display whatever is in the nested IF statement attached at the end. Why am I getting an

> object defined error

```
With .Range("AX2")
    .Formula = "=IF(F2="""",VLOOKUP(A2,[PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$A:$AG,33,FALSE),IF(AR176<=300000,AR176*0.3,IF(AND(AR176>300000,AR176<=500000),((AR176-300000)*0.35)+90000,IF(AND(AR176>500000,AR176<=1000000),((AR176-500000)*0.4)+160000,IF(AR176>1000000,((AR176-1000000)*0.45)+360000,))))))"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("AX2:AX" & lastrow)
End With
```

Comment: Did you try using the macro recorder whilst writing this formula in a cell to compare some of the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

A:AG is only 33 columns, not 34. Try changing to 33 or the range to A:AH,

```
With .Range("AX2:AX" & lastrow)
    .Formula = "=IF(F2=text(,), VLOOKUP(A2,$A:$AG, 33, FALSE), IF(AR176<=300000, AR176*0.3, IF(AR176<=500000, (AR176-300000)*0.35+90000, IF(AR176<=1000000, (AR176-500000)*0.4+160000, (AR176-1000000)*0.45+360000))))"
End With
```

Comment: I tried that edit and I'm still getting an defined object error

Comment: Looks like you also had an extra `)` on the end.